# How to capture the new id of a record created in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I want to trigger an action to use the new id of a record created in react-admin immediately after the record has been created.

What's the best way to do this?

Here are some ideas based on [the props you can pass to SimpleForm/TabbedForm](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#the-simpleform-component) and [this issue by one of the project maintainers](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2905).

- Wrap the `save` function passed to the form.
- Create a custom `toolbar` and Save button for my form, try to hook it there.
- Use the form `redirect` prop to redirect to a temporary page where I do the work on the new id.

Alternatively,

- Try to hook into the form lifecycle events using the [redux-form API](https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/reduxform.md).
- Put some extra code in my custom data provider to trigger my action.

Any other ideas?

Comment: you can use local storage as well localStorage.setItem("YourId", IDValue) and read it anywhere in your app using localStorage.getItem("YourId")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom saga and handle the CRUD_CREATE_SUCCESS action:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#custom-sagas

```
createSuccessSaga.js

import {
  put,
  takeEvery,
} from 'redux-saga/effects'

import {
  CRUD_CREATE_SUCCESS,
} from 'react-admin'

function* createSuccess(action) {
  try {                        
    console.log('createSuccess:', action) // action.payload.data.id -> Record ID     
    yield put('you action')              
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('createSuccess:', error) 
  }
}

function* createSuccessSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(CRUD_CREATE_SUCCESS, createSuccess) 
}

export default createSuccessSaga
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the official answer although I probably won't use this method because I don't have to perform a simple and pure side effect. With the addition of this method though, I think all of the options have been found. Thanks.